# How to display all the values from one table but on two columns in that table, display the value of other tables if their column name is the same

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a table that I will get all the values from.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DiagnosticLog]
(
    [DiagnosticLogID]   [int]       NOT NULL identity(-2147483648,1),
    [ServerID]          [int]       NOT NULL, --changed to int for now
    [MessageID]         [smallint]      NOT NULL,
    [Something]         [bigint]        NOT NULL,
    [SomethingElse]         [varchar](100)  NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate]            [smalldatetime] NOT NULL
)
```

I want to replace the MessageID in the first table with the MessageDescription in the second table when the value of the MessageID in the tables are the same.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Message]
(
              [MessageID]     [smallint]     IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
              [MessageDescription]    [varchar](100)   NOT NULL,
              [CreateDate]     [datetime]    NOT NULL
)
```

same with the ServerID column. The value of ServerID column from the first table will be the value of ServerName when the value of the ServerID's are the same.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Server]
(
    [ServerID]          [smallint]      NOT NULL identity(1,1),
    [ServerName]            [char](20)      NOT NULL,
    [ServerPort]            [int]           NOT NULL,
    [ServerIP]              [char](20)      NOT NULL,
    [CacheType]             [char](10)      NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate]            [datetime]      NOT NULL
)
```

If I do this query I can get some of the information I want but I want the Message Description to replace MessageId.

```
SELECT * from DiagnosticLog INNER JOIN  Message  on DiagnosticLog.EBCPMessageID = Message.MessageID
```

Also, I'm learning about indexing for SQL. What would be a good way for me to make indexes on the tables so it queries faster? Would I create an index on MessageID and ServerID?

Comment: just for the next time: don't use a ultralong sentence as headline. try to describe it with a few words

Comment: why do you want to replace the IDs in your first table? i would keep the design, as it is. furthermore: have a look here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp - if i got it right, you could put a primary key on the ID of each table. if you need any further indexes, really depends on the queries you're running against your tables

Comment: @EstebanP. I'll try to keep my titles shorter next time. Also, I wanted to replace the MessageID b/c what I want to actually display is the MessageDescription from the second table when the MessageID are equal to each other. For example, if MessageID=1 in both tables it will display the MessageDescription in the second table

Comment: @SqlZim wow that's perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want a query, not to actually update any values. You can do this with a `left join` to each of the referenced tables and using `isnull()` to determine if there is a corresponding value, and if not, use the `ID`:

```
select
    dl.DiagnosticLogID
  , ServerID  = isnull(s.ServerName,convert(char(20),dl.ServerID))
  , MessageID = isnull(m.MessageDescription,convert(varchar(100),dl.MessageID))
  , dl.Something
  , dl.SomethingElse
  , dl.CreateDate
from dbo.DiagnosticLog dl
  left join dbo.Message m
    on dl.MessageID = m.MessageID
  left join dbo.Server s
    on dl.ServerID = s.ServerID
```

---

You say 'when the value of MessageID is the same', so I have used `left join`s. If there will always be a corresponding row, you can use `inner join`s instead, and you would not need to account for `null` values:

```
select
    dl.DiagnosticLogID
  , ServerID  = s.ServerName
  , MessageID = m.MessageDescription
  , dl.Something
  , dl.SomethingElse
  , dl.CreateDate
from dbo.DiagnosticLog dl
  inner join dbo.Message m
    on dl.MessageID = m.MessageID
  inner join dbo.Server s
    on dl.ServerID = s.ServerID
```